# How do I resolve an error with not build wheels for hidapi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: google-coral

`coralmicro % bash setup.sh
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################### 100.0%
Warning: Treating cmake as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/cmake
Warning: cmake 3.27.6 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.27.6, run:
brew reinstall cmake
Warning: libusb 1.0.26 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.0.26, run:
brew reinstall libusb
Warning: lsusb 1.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.0, run:
brew reinstall lsusb
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (23.2.1)
Collecting hexformat==0.2 (from -r /Users/danielcagney/documents/coralmicro/scripts/requirements.txt (line 1))
Using cached hexformat-0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hidapi==0.10.1 (from -r /Users/danielcagney/documents/coralmicro/scripts/requirements.txt (line 2))
Using cached hidapi-0.10.1.tar.gz (60 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting progress==1.5 (from -r /Users/danielcagney/documents/coralmicro/scripts/requirements.txt (line 3))
Using cached progress-1.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyserial==3.5 (from -r /Users/danielcagney/documents/coralmicro/scripts/requirements.txt (line 4))
Using cached pyserial-3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting pyusb==1.2.0 (from -r /Users/danielcagney/documents/coralmicro/scripts/requirements.txt (line 5))
Using cached pyusb-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=19.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from hidapi==0.10.1->-r /Users/danielcagney/documents/coralmicro/scripts/requirements.txt (line 2)) (68.1.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: hidapi
Building wheel for hidapi (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [19 lines of output]
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
!!
!!
dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
Compiling hid.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing hid.pyx
/private/var/folders/th/c5bb5d0d4nvfytxblkshzdhw0000gn/T/pip-install-__i68mir/hidapi_95004ab0156645e5beeeaca9bdeb6eed/.eggs/Cython-3.0.2-py3.11.egg/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:384: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /private/var/folders/th/c5bb5d0d4nvfytxblkshzdhw0000gn/T/pip-install-__i68mir/hidapi_95004ab0156645e5beeeaca9bdeb6eed/hid.pyx
tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
building 'hid' extension
error: unknown file type '.pxd' (from 'chid.pxd')
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for hidapi
Running setup.py clean for hidapi
Failed to build hidapi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hidapi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have tried running a bash setup.sh, then this error occurs.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the build.sh (which comes next in the coral micro starting guide) worked (after uninstalling hidapi and reinstalling as in the Dockerfile). And also flashing the scripts on the board. So I figure it's a problem with this specific script, that has no further impact. But I'll keep my eyes open.

Comment: Can be a comment but not an answer